# как Отправить несколько email в Laravel 5,8?

Tags: laravel, email

делал по этому принципу https://web-programming.com.ua/otpravka-email-v-laravel-ispolzuya-smtp/

```
вот контролер
public function send() {
    $comment = 'Это сообщение отправлено из формы обратной связи';
    $toEmail = "test@mail.test";
    Mail::to($toEmail)->send(new FeedbackMail($comment));
    return 'Сообщение отправлено на адрес '. $toEmail;
}
менял так и все равно
public function send() {
    $comment = 'Это сообщение отправлено из формы обратной связи';
    $toEmail = "test@mail.test";
    Mail::to($toEmail)->сс(['test@mail.test3, test@mail.test2'])send(new FeedbackMail($comment));
    return 'Сообщение отправлено на адрес '. $toEmail;
}
```

но так только 1 майл отсылается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В метод `to` передавай массив. У меня так работает без проблем

```
Mail::to(['email1@example.com','email2@example.com'])->send(new OrderShipped($request->all()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример по которому вы делаете использует очередь для отправки писем.

При любом изменении писем вам надо сделать рестарт очередей.

```
php artisan queue:restart
```